# Запуск процесса с правами обычного пользователя от лица администратора

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

Программа запускается под админом. Из самой проги хочу запустить другой процесс, но без прав админа, т.е. как обычного пользователя:

```
   Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyConfig.exe";
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
```

в манифесте дочернего процесса я указал
`<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />`

Проверяю запущена ли форма под правами админа или нет: запускается с теми же правами, что и родительский процесс. Где моя ошибка?

Comment: Вам так же нужен `runas` при запуске как делается при элевации прав до админа, только для него надо задать какие-то свои параметры. В манифесте при этом скорее всего ничего специально указывать не нужно.

Comment: что я толькок не перепробовал... не могу добиться толка

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Указание в манифесте `asInvoker` ни к чему не обязывает, ибо согласно официальной документации M$ (и просто логике) приложение будет исполняться на том же уровне привилегий, что и вызывающий его процесс.

Поставленная задача может быть решена различными способами. Одно из возможных решений можно представить в виде цепочки вызовов `GetShellWindow` -> `GetWindowThreadProcessId` -> `OpenProcessToken` -> `DuplicateTokenEx` -> `CreateProcessWithToken` (в двух словах - просто тырим токен), примерно так (вариант на коленке):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace RunWithLowerRights {
  internal static class NativeMethods {
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct LUID {
      internal UInt32 LowPart;
      internal Int32  HighPart;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES {
      internal LUID   Luid;
      internal UInt32 Attributes;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct TOKEN_PRIVILEGES {
      internal UInt32 PrivilegeCount;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]
      internal LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[] Privileges;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct PROCESS_INFORMATION {
      internal IntPtr hProcess;
      internal IntPtr hThread;
      internal UInt32 dwProcessId;
      internal UInt32 dwThreadId;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal struct STARTUPINFO {
      internal UInt32 cd;
      internal String lpReserved;
      internal String lpDesktop;
      internal String lpTitle;
      internal UInt32 dwX;
      internal UInt32 dwY;
      internal UInt32 dwXSize;
      internal UInt32 dwYSize;
      internal UInt32 dwXCountChars;
      internal UInt32 dwYCountChars;
      internal UInt32 dwFillAttribute;
      internal UInt32 dwFlags;
      internal UInt16 wShowWindow;
      internal UInt16 cbReserved2;
      internal IntPtr lpReserved2;
      internal IntPtr hStdInput;
      internal IntPtr hStdOutput;
      internal IntPtr hStdError;
    }

    internal enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL : uint {
      SecurityAnonymous,
      SecurityIdentification,
      SecurityImpersonation,
      SecurityDelegation
    }

    internal enum TOKEN_TYPE : uint {
      TokenPrimary = 1,
      TokenImpersonation
    }

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern Boolean AdjustTokenPrivileges(
       IntPtr TokenHandle,
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]Boolean DisableAllPrivileges,
       ref TOKEN_PRIVILEGES NewState,
       UInt32 BufferLength,
       IntPtr PreviousState, // ref TOKEN_PRIVILEGES PreviousState
       IntPtr ReturnLength   // out UInt32 ReturnLength
    );

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern Boolean CreateProcessWithToken(
       IntPtr hToken,
       UInt32 dwLogonFlags,
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]String lpApplicationName,
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]String lpCommandLine,
       UInt32 dwCreationFlags,
       IntPtr lpEnvironment,
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]String lpCurrentDirectory,
       ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
       out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
    );

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern Boolean DuplicateTokenEx(
       IntPtr hExistingToken,
       UInt32 dwDesiredAccess,
       IntPtr lpTokenAttributes,
       SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL ImpersonationLevel,
       TOKEN_TYPE TokenType,
       out IntPtr phNewToken
    );

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern Boolean LookupPrivilegeValue(
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]String lpSystemName,
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]String lpName,
       ref LUID lpLuid
    );

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern Boolean OpenProcessToken(
       IntPtr ProcessHandle,
       UInt32 DesiredAccess,
       ref IntPtr TokenHandle
    );

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern Boolean CloseHandle(
       IntPtr Handle
    );

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(
       UInt32 dwDesiredAccess,
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]Boolean bInheritHandle,
       UInt32 dwProcessId
    );

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern UInt32 GetWindowThreadProcessId(
       IntPtr hWnd,
       out UInt32 lpdwProcessId
    );

    internal static void GetLastError() {
      Console.WriteLine(new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message);
    }

    internal static void RunAsRegularUser(String path) {
      var token = IntPtr.Zero;
      var privs = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGES {
        PrivilegeCount = 1,
        Privileges = new LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[1]
      };

      var shell = IntPtr.Zero;
      var c_sps = IntPtr.Zero;
      var c_stk = IntPtr.Zero;
      var c_usr = IntPtr.Zero;

      var si = new STARTUPINFO();
      var pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();

      try {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
          throw new ArgumentException("Путь до исполняемого файла не может быть пустым.");
        if (!OpenProcessToken((IntPtr)(-1), 0x20, ref token))
          throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(null, "SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege", ref privs.Privileges[0].Luid))
          throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        privs.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0x02;
        if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(token, false, ref privs, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
          throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        shell = GetShellWindow();
        if (IntPtr.Zero == shell)
          throw new InvalidOperationException("Вызов GetShellWindow ничего не вернул.");

        UInt32 pid = 0;
        if (0 == GetWindowThreadProcessId(shell, out pid))
          throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        c_sps = OpenProcess(0x400, false, pid);
        if (IntPtr.Zero == c_sps)
          throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        if (!OpenProcessToken(c_sps, 0x02, ref c_stk))
          throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        if (!DuplicateTokenEx(c_stk, 0x18B, IntPtr.Zero,
           SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation, TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary, out c_usr))
          throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        if (!CreateProcessWithToken(c_usr, 0, path, null, 0,
                                         IntPtr.Zero, Path.GetDirectoryName(path), ref si, out pi))
          throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        if (!CloseHandle(pi.hProcess)) GetLastError();
        if (!CloseHandle(pi.hThread))  GetLastError();
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
      }
      finally {
        if (IntPtr.Zero != c_usr) if (!CloseHandle(c_usr)) GetLastError();
        if (IntPtr.Zero != c_stk) if (!CloseHandle(c_stk)) GetLastError();
        if (IntPtr.Zero != c_sps) if (!CloseHandle(c_sps)) GetLastError();
        if (IntPtr.Zero != token) if (!CloseHandle(token)) GetLastError();
      }
    }
  } // NativeMethods

  internal sealed class Program {
    static void Main() {
      NativeMethods.RunAsRegularUser(@"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe");
    }
  } // Program
}
```

Вызов из консоли администратора должен запустить консоль с правами обычного пользователя.

Comment: Да, проверок тьма. Если ты сам автор этого кода, то респект отдельныйю. Псомотрел код, проверил - он рабочий. Есть попутный вопрос....Когда стартуешь процесс используя Process proc = new Process(); то есть такая возможность, как ожидание завершения процесса WaitForExit(). Что-то подобное можно реализвать  и тут ?

Comment: @АлександрПузанов `WaitForExit` можно, конечно, реализовать самостоятельно, но куда проще получить экземпляр `Process` для запущенного процесса, например, `var ps = Process.GetprocessById(...)`, а дальше сделать `ps.WaitForExit()`. Что касается проверок, повторюсь, писалось на коленке, так что выхолить код, ежели он принят в качестве ответа, уже на совести задавшего вопрос.

Comment: По поводу проверок -то это сказано было мной в плюс

Answer (score 1):

1. Создать юзера с необходимым уровнем прав доступа и задать ему пароль
2. зайти под этим юзером

```
var credentials = new UserCredentials(domain, username, password);
Impersonation.RunAsUser(credentials, logonType, () =>
{
    сделать все что необходимо, например запустить программу.
});
```

используя нюгет [SimpleImpersonation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleImpersonation)

---

> Мне нужно не от любого по выбору [пользователя], а от обычного Users

По поводу желания запустить от имени группы "USERS" мне кажется что это невозможно в силу того, что ЭТО НЕ РЕАЛЬНЫЙ ЮЗЕР, а просто некие настройки дефолтного уровня прав доступа. Или же группа пользователей, но не реальный юзер. Поправьте если я ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы запускать процессы от имени других пользователей, для начала вам нужно зайти в систему под его именем, чтобы получить SID и токен этого юзера. Для этого существует функция `LogonUser()`, которая возвращает токен. Теперь вы можете использовать его при вызове `CreateProcessAsUser()`, чтобы запускать процессы от имени других пользователей. Именно такого алго придерживается утилита **runas**. Ознакомиться с деталями можно на [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera).

Comment: Мне нужно не от любого по выбору, а от обычного Users, что по умолчанию и права минимальные. Но этот ответ наталкивает на просвет...